# Registering a Custom Event Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics

i'm facing a problem here with Firebase analytics, in the documentation there is no explanation for how to add a custom Event (the docs specify how to add a custom event parameter not an event), and in the sample code it just shows that you set the event name with a String according to your need.

```
Analytics.logEvent("Custom_Event", parameters: [
  "name": name as NSObject,
  "full_text": text as NSObject
  ])
```

after using sample code this there are no events in the dashboard regarding this event.

question here is this sufficient? and does it get registered automatically? if so do i also have to register custom event params for every event? or the custom event parameters should only be registered for pre defined events .

Comment: You need to create conversations on the console, then you can try to run your custom event... after 24 ish hours your conversation will show up in the events tab, then you can add your parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wait at least 24 hours to see the events on the console.

What u can use is **Debug View** in Firebase to check the events are getting logged

DebugView enables you to see the raw event data logged by your app on development devices in near real-time

For more info [How to enable Debug View](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview)